# inserting 4 datas into database but its adding only 2nd data in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

when inserting data into a table only 2nd data is added by the function. why are the other data not getting added into the table? whats wrong in the code?

```
public function create($db,$table,array $columns,array $values){
//"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db";
    $this->connection->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db");

    $this->connection->select_db($db);

    $this->connection->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 $columns[0] varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 $columns[1] varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 $columns[2] varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 $columns[3] varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;");

    for ($i=0;$i<count($columns);$i++) {
        $this->connection->query("INSERT INTO $table ($columns[$i]) VALUES ($values[$i])");
        echo $i."<br>".$columns[$i]."<br>".$values[$i]."<br>";
    }
}

$process=strtolower($_POST['select']);
$db=$_POST['database'];
$table=$_POST['table'];
$columns=explode(",", $_POST['columns']);
$values=explode(",", $_POST['values']);

if($process == "create"){
    $obj->create($db,$table,$columns,$values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You have defined a table with five non-`NULL` columns that have no default values.  You are then inserting into the table one column at a time.  Each insert is going to fail, because the other columns are being set to `NULL`, and that is not allowed.

Fix your code so you insert one row with all the values for the columns at the same time.

Comment: if all insert is going to fail,then why is the 2nd data is getting added? every time i insert data only the 2nd data is added to the table.

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen . . . My guess is that the table already exists with that record.  You could actually add in a `createdAt` column with a default of the current timestamp to see when rows are being inserted.

Comment: no , everytime i insert data its added to a new row, like i did this 5 time now there is 5 row and only all the third column has values

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen . . . Are you sure the columns are really declared as `NOT NULL`?  Can you edit your question and add an example of what each insert statement looks like?

Comment: $_POST has following data
 Array
(
    [select] => Create
    [database] => zend
    [table] => students
    [columns] => name,mobile,email,address
    [values] => roman,017666666,gf@es.co,dhanmondi
    [submit] => submit
)

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen . . . That doesn't look like the `insert` statement being passed to `$this->connection->query()`.

Comment: $process=strtolower($_POST['select']);
$db=$_POST['database'];
$table=$_POST['table'];
$columns=explode(",", $_POST['columns']);
$values=explode(",", $_POST['values']);

if($process == "create"){
    $obj->create($db,$table,$columns,$values);
}

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written this loop it will be inserting a new row for each occurance in the `$columns` array. This will create 4 rows each with a single column containing a value.

What you want to do is create the column list and the value list seperately and then run one query that will insert one row with all the columns set to a value.

Try this instead :-

```
$col_list = '';
$val_list = '';
foreach ( $columns as $idx => $column ) {
    $col_list .= $column . ',';
    $val_list .= "'$values[$idx]',";
}
// remove the trailing commas
$col_list = rtrim($col_list, ',');
$val_list = rtrim($val_list, ',');

$this->connection->query("INSERT INTO $table ($col_list) VALUES ($val_list)";
```

This should run one query to insert one row where all 4 columns has a value.

You have done nothing to check that the values passed to you from the screen contain what you expect, or that there are actually 4 fields and 4 values in the data you are passed, and do not contain any dangerous values. **I assume you just left this validation code out for brevity** so I will not remind you about sanity checking such data passed from the browser.

Comment: No it didn't create 4 rows rather then just 1 row with a single column containing a value

Comment: Because all 4 column definitions include `NOT NULL` it should not have created any rows, just 4 mysql errors. Anyway, this is a a correct way of doing what you are trying to do. I am sure you only wanted to create ONE ROW but yours would create 4 with only one column containing data in any of the rows

Comment: another problem is when i give a new table name it doesn't create the table,why?

Comment: yeah it did, but other problem is when i give a new table name it doesn't create a table

Comment: Sorry but you are going to have to ask another question to get an answer to that.